# How to make a variable after a certain integer in python

Tags: python-3.x

Im brand new to programing this is literally my second day just looking at this stuff. So please forgive me if this is answered somewhere already or if its a really dumb question, this is still like witch craft to me.

Anyways I have to make a pay calculator and I want to make a variable for anything after 40 to be overtime. This is what I have so far.

```
input("Enter Name, Or 0 To Quit: ")
hour = float(input("Hours: "))
if hour > 40:

    overTime = float(print("Over Time Hours: "))
    payRate = float(input("Pay Rate: $ "))

    overTime = overTimeHour * 1.5
    grossPay = hour * payRate + overTime

    print("\nGross Pay: $", (grossPay))
else:
    payRate = float(input("Pay Rate: $ "))

    grossPay = hour * payRate

    print("\nGross Pay: $",(grossPay))
```

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what problem you are trying to address. Rephrase the question to include what you expect to see - provide sample inputs and expected outputs, and then the actual outputs you are getting. If you are getting errors instead, then share those.

Comment: I want to create the overTimeHour variable which would be anything after 40 hours, but I also need it to be just whatever number after 40 like if its 45 hours I just want the 5 to count as overtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want your overTime variable to be a float(print()). That'll probably throw an error. You already have the total number of hours, so isn't the number of overtime hours just hours - 40? I don't think you need another input for that. Then, you need to change up your formula for gross pay a bit.

I also moved the input for payRate out, since it applies to both conditions in the if statement.

The following code should do the trick:

```
input("Enter Name, Or 0 To Quit: ")
hour = float(input("Hours: "))
payRate = float(input("Pay Rate: $ "))
if hour > 40:

    overTimeHours = hour - 40

    # This can be simplified (via commutative property) if you'd like
    grossPay = (40 * payRate) + (overTimeHours * 1.5 * payRate)

    print("\nGross Pay: $", (grossPay))
else:
    grossPay = hour * payRate

    print("\nGross Pay: $",(grossPay))
```

Comment: The whole overTimeHours = hour - 40 was a real eyeopener... I guess I was trying to think to hard like there was some command to do that for me....Thanks for pointing all these out!

Comment: Haha no problem, we all start somewhere! :)